# Modeling Composite Design Pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, uml

I'm using Java Eclipse EMF to model my Composite Pattern. What would be the right UML representation to model aa new class (Root) which implements a unique root directory. This is the original Composite pattern.

[image]

This is my representation:

[image]

Target representation would be:

```
root
  |___ dir1
  |___ dir2
  |___ dir3
  |      |___ fileA
  |      |___ dir4
  |             |__ fileB
  |    
  |___ file1
```

Comment: If Root class will only implement a new instance of Directory I guess the relationship should be connected to Directory not the Component.

Comment: Isnt the point of Composite pattern is to provide the Client a unique interface which could be either a Composite or Leaf? "The Composite composes objects into tree structures and lets clients treat individual objects and compositions uniformly."

Comment: What's that lonely open triangle in the middle? That's no UML element at all.

Answer (score 2):

Your diagrams are wrong.

First, the `add`, `remove`, and `getChild` SHOULD NOT be on `Component`. That is pretty obvious from [image on wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern). Especially in your case, where all of those operations make no sense for `File`.

The second issue is the `operation` method. The composite means that if you call operation on the `Composite`, then it delegates it to it's children. And when client of `Component` is using it, it doesn't care if it is using just single leaf, composite or complex tree of composites and leafs.

Comment: This is a debate raised initially at the GoF book (Page 167) which is a decision of a trade-off between transparency and safety. http://wiki.c2.com/?CompositePattern "Defining the child management interface at the root of the class hierarchy gives you transparency, because you can treat all components uniformly. It cost you safety, however, because clients may try to do meaningless things like add and remove from leaves"

Answer (score 1):

Your current diagram indicates that `FileSystem` uses either a single file (without any directories) or a directory tree.

I understand that the actual requirement is that a `FileSystem` always consists of a directory tree of at least one directory (root) and contents of that root directory, which can be sub-directories.
This can best be modeled by having a composition arrow from `FileSystem` to `Directory`.

The fact that `FileSystem` directly links to `Directory` does not mean or imply in any way that the other classes in the composite pattern can not be used by `FileSystem`. The arrow only indicates that the root is a directory.